# Replace character strings cannot be done

Tags: python

Replace character strings cannot be done.Now I have a character strings whose variable is x is like `x = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.` I want to replace "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt" into the number of length of the character strings of ⚪︎ .I wrote codes,

```
x = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
y = re.search("sed do.+?incididunt", x).group()
print(y)
ans = re.sub(y, ''.ljust(len(y), '〇'), x)
print(ans)
```

But now when  I run this codes, nothing is replaced.

My ideal output is:

`print(ans)` shows `x = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 〇〇〇 〇〇 〇〇〇〇〇〇〇 〇〇〇〇〇〇 〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇 ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."`

`print(y)` shows `"sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"`.

Why can't I replace this? How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https://repl.it/repls/OpaquePowerfulProgrammingmacro

Your code appears to do exactly what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and everything worked well. Try and run one more time.
I got the correct output.